# Name of a single-conductor coax test cable

Tags: connector, cables, coaxial

Alright, bit of a silly question but I can't seem to get Digikey or Mouser to show me what I want.

I'm wanting to replicate Fig. 7 of this [INA116 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina116.pdf) almost exactly. Before I go and buy this expensive IC, I'm mapping out how I'll build the coax setup at the top of Fig. 5; I'm having difficulty figuring out what cable and connector I'll use, though.
[image: Fig 7]
[image: Fig 5]

What I'm imagining is a single conductor coaxial cable that features a BNC or SMA at one end and a minigrabber / alligator clip / kelvin clip / similar at the other end (I use a mix of custom and standard electrodes with both planar and pin contact geometries); the BNC or SMA allows me to tie the coax shield to my guard loops on the PCB. However, the search terms I'm using for Digikey and Mouser turn up either unterminated coax spools or BNC test cables where the connector shield is just a separate wire (therefore, not coax at all).

Does someone know what the correct search term is for what I'm looking for? Or is this something uncommon enough that I'll have to make custom cables?

Thanks!

Comment: Cable Assemblies - such as "coax cable assemblies sma" gets a million and a half replies from Google.

Comment: I would expect any test cable with a BNC connector would be coax - it may end with two short wires with some type of clips, but the majority of the cable will be coax.

Comment: What @PeterBennett said.  If you want a different termination than you can find from a "regular" source, get one coax that's terminated with BNC or SMA at both ends, cut it in half, and terminate it yourself.

Comment: As well, you probably want coax with a Teflon dielectric for ultra low leakage. A standard foam dielectric coax might be too leaky for your application.

Comment: Peter and Tim: Yeah, I thought that may end up being the case. I suppose it isn't a huge deal to tie the second cable back with a zip-tie, just figured I'd end up with with some stray induction. I'll just tie it back as linearly as I can.
Kartman: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind when I look again.